# How to get another user's profile in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to set a cookie with a user's timezone when they login.  AccountController.LogOn() seems like the best place to do this.  However, I can't yet read a user's profile there since I guess you only have access to profiles when the method completes.  So, this code returns an empty string:

```
Dim timeZone = HttpContext.Profile("TZ").ToString
```

Once a user has fully logged on, the above code returns the correct TimeZone.

One solution is to read the profile for the username trying to log on in AccountController.LogOn():

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(username);  // FAILS
```

However, this doesn't work.

So, how do I read a given user's profile if they're not logged in?

Comment: How does Profile.GetProfile fail? What is the exception?

Comment: Profile.GetProfile() doesn't appear to exist for MVC apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this doesnt look obvious but is a get Profile:

```
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(HttpContext.Profile.UserName, true);
```

returns an existing instance.

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware of ProfileBase.Create(), but I thought it created new profiles for users who did not have one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mathias' answer, you can then cast it to your typed profile:

```
ProfileCommon profile = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(username, true);
```

Also, the documentation for [ProfileBase.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151826(loband).aspx) is on MSDN.